# restore postgres BBDD - message "already exists"

Tags: restore

I do a pg_dump from RDS, this dump need to restore en local develop context

```
psql -U postgres -d devDDB -f /tmp/prodDDBB.sql
```

and too many errors jump, like:

```
psql:/tmp/prodDDBB.sql:123255: ERROR:  duplicate key value violates unique constraint "operation_keys_pkey"
DETAIL:  Key (id)=(1088) already exists.

psql:/tmp/prodDDBB.sql:226882: ERROR:  relation "brands_vehicles_account_index" already exists
```

this is normal on a restore operation? the database already exist, i guess this s normal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use

```
-c
--clean
```

> Output commands to clean (drop) database objects prior to outputting the commands for creating them. (Unless --if-exists is also specified, restore might generate some harmless error messages, if any objects were not present in the destination database.)

> This option is only meaningful for the plain-text format. For the archive formats, you can specify the option when you call pg_restore.

see [manual](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/10/app-pgdump.html)

so that all elemenst are dropped before you restore the database.

in your case use `pg_restore` with the same parameter, that has the same effect

Comment: thanks, that's right

Comment: @JorgeMansoN please [accept te answer](https://dba.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers) if it was helpful

Comment: i still can't vote, but i can accept the solution

Comment: you need 15 rep for that, keep up and you will quickly reach it